# Как мне выбрать наилучший вариант реализации для клиент-серверного приложения при использовании Twisted?

Tags: python, pyrogram, scrapy, playwright, twisted

*Меня интересует программирование на Pyhton, и на данный момент я хочу изучить Twisted.*
*Я придерживаюсь позиции, что гораздо эффективнее изучать что-либо, решая практические задачи.*

### Описание проекта:

Клиент-серверное приложение, позволяющее:

1. Задавайте вопросы на [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com /)
2. Отслеживайте ответы и комментарии к этим вопросам
3. Комментируйте и отвечайте в комментариях
4. Обновляйте, закрывайте и удаляйте созданные вопросы.

***Stackoverflow выбран потому, что у него есть [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs),***
***что означает, что этот проект не будет иметь приоритета перед использованием API.***
***Этот проект может быть полезен для взаимодействия со службами, которые не предоставляют доступ к API.***
(Поправьте меня, если использовать Stackoverflow не правильно.)

### Интерфейс:

[Telegram](https://telegram.org/?1) будет использоваться в качестве интерфейса как для клиентской, так и для серверной частей.
(Используемая библиотека - [pyrogram](https://pyrogram.org /).)

Начал читать [документацию](https://docs.twistedmatrix.com/en/stable/core/examples/), там много примеров и я растерялся не знаю какой вариант выбрать для реализации.

***Сам сайт наверное позже изменю, это не важно.***
***Суть в том что авторизация нужна на стороне клиента,***
***а серверная часть имитирует действия пользователя в браузере используя авторизацию,***
***(что бы серверная часть не получала и не хранила логин и пароль).***

### Какой шаблон Twisted выбрать для реализации подобного?

Comment: Буду рад отзывам относительно постановки вопроса.